# Jooq select record type seems to be reading columns by index incorrectly

Tags: jooq

We have a user table we can select from like so...

```
   Result<Record1<PortalUserRecord>> userList = dsl.select(Tables.PORTAL_USER).from(Tables.PORTAL_USER).fetch();
```

Sometimes this works as expected (returns all users).  However ussually it seems to do this...

```
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select cast (row ("portal_user".*) as "portal_user") as "portal_user" from "portal_user"]; Error while reading field: cast (row ("planglobal"."portal_user".*) as "planglobal"."portal_user"), at JDBC index: 1
    at org.jooq_3.17.4.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq_3.17.4.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3307)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:678)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1464)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.hasNext(CursorImpl.java:1425)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:238)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.fetch(AbstractCursor.java:177)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.fetch(AbstractCursor.java:88)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:265)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:341)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:290)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2837)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.backend.admin.UserJooqAdmin.listAll(UserJooqAdmin.java:125)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.ui.crud.AbstractJooqCrudView.<init>(AbstractJooqCrudView.java:68)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.ui.crud.CompanyDependentJooqCrudView.<init>(CompanyDependentJooqCrudView.java:33)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.ui.crud.CompanyDependentJooqCrudView.<init>(CompanyDependentJooqCrudView.java:28)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.ui.views.UsersListView.<init>(UsersListView.java:59)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.ui.views.UsersListView$$FastClassByGuice$$137473960.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(<generated>)
    at com.sferion.planglobal.ui.views.UsersListView$$FastClassByGuice$$137473960.apply(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:300)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1101)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while reading field: cast (row ("planglobal"."portal_user".*) as "planglobal"."portal_user"), at JDBC index: 1
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1590)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.apply(CursorImpl.java:1525)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.apply(CursorImpl.java:1484)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:144)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1449)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2022-10-17 20:57:11.795537"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:711)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1163)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultRecordBinding.pgFromString(DefaultBinding.java:3873)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultRecordBinding.pgSetValue(DefaultBinding.java:3984)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultRecordBinding.lambda$pgNewRecord$13(DefaultBinding.java:3976)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:144)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultRecordBinding.pgNewRecord(DefaultBinding.java:3972)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultRecordBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:3767)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultRecordBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:3687)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$InternalBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:1025)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1580)
```

It is very strange to me that sometimes this query works and sometimes I get an error for the exact query. From what I can tell selecting Tables.PORTAL_USER generates an asterisk query but the column orders are not consistent.  This makes me wonder what would cause that?  A bug in postgres? The JDBC driver?  Something wrong with the latest release of jooq (3.17.4) as of writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the new jOOQ 3.17 [`Table` as `SelectField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/) feature, which has a native implementation on PostgreSQL, while being emulated elsewhere. E.g. in native PostgreSQL, it's possible to write:

```sql
SELECT t FROM t
```

Producing a nested record from your projection, rather than a flat result set. In your particular case, that's not necessary. You can flatten your result set like this:

```java
Result<PortalUserRecord> userList = 
    dsl.selectFrom(PORTAL_USER).fetch();
```

It's simpler, and doesn't run into this bug. It's certainly a bug in jOOQ (another bug caused by the native PG-specific implementation of said [`Table` as `SelectField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/) feature. The `*` (asterisk) is at fault here, although omitting it as in the SQL example above, would expose the same problem. The problem being that this syntax relies on the column order of the database instance, rather than on the column order of the generated code. (This is why jOOQ never generates the `*` for ordinary queries either, but always lists all columns explicitly). Using this syntax would require a lot of database change management diligence, to make sure all development, test, production database instances expose the exact same database meta data.

After numerous other issues with the native implementation of the feature

- [#13664](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13664) Avoid ambiguous reference when using Table as SelectField for table conflicting with column
- [#13843](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13843) Cannot use Table as SelectField from derived table where nesting records is supported natively
- [#13988](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13988) Table as SelectField doesn't work from unnamed scalar subquery in PostgreSQL

I'd say, this should be the last straw to remove the implementation, and emulate the feature also on PostgreSQL:

- [#14100](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14100) Table as SelectField native support relies on actual column order, not generated order

As a workaround, you should avoid the feature, or ensure the generation schema matches the production schema *exactly*.

Comment: Your fix in 14100 would have masked a problem we have.  The database had incorrect column orders due to a bug in our code that uses flywaydb to setup the db for testing.  Either way maybe select * is a bad idea because something as simple as column order can break a query.  3.17.4 actually works fine with native postgres support using select *.

Comment: @benstpierre: Well, #14100 is consistent with what jOOQ has been doing for 13 years now in all other queries where you don't explicitly project individual columns. So, your problem helped unmask a significant flaw of the previous implementation, if you will. Rather than using an unrelated feature to detect metadata flaws, I recommend running checks on your metadata directly.